# Compiling AOSP Kernel with KASAN

Tags: android, linux, kernel, android-source, address-sanitizer

I'm struggling to compile the Linux kernel for usage in AOSP with KASAN & KCOV enabled. I then intend to flash it to a Pixel 2 XL (taimen) and use Syzkaller to fuzz it.

This is what I did:

**1. Build unmodified kernel (works)**

My reference: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels

- Determine branch... `android-msm-wahoo-4.4-pie-qpr2`
- `$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b android-msm-wahoo-4.4-pie-qpr2`
- `$ repo sync -j8 -c`
- `$ build/build.sh -j8`
- Connect phone via USB
- `$ adb reboot bootloader`
- `$ fastboot boot out/android-msm-wahoo-4.4/dist/Image.lz4-dtb`
  (Works fine)

**2. Build kernel with KASAN & KCOV (fails)**

- To change kernel config symbols, edit `POST_DEFCONFIG_CMDS` in build/build.config

  - Copy from https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels#customize-config
  - Modify as needed, use `-d` to disable, `-e` to enable a config option
  - Result:

```
POST_DEFCONFIG_CMDS="check_defconfig && update_debug_config"
function update_debug_config() {
    ${KERNEL_DIR}/scripts/config --file ${OUT_DIR}/.config \
         -d CONFIG_KERNEL_LZ4 \
         -e CONFIG_KASAN \
         -e CONFIG_KASAN_INLINE \
         -e CONFIG_KCOV \
         -e CONFIG_SLUB \
         -e CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG \
         --set-val FRAME_WARN 0
    (cd ${OUT_DIR} && \
     make O=${OUT_DIR} $archsubarch CC=${CC} CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE} olddefconfig)
}
```

- `$ build/build.sh -j8`

But after
`CHK     include/generated/compile.h`
I get many undefined reference errors to various asan-symbols, e.g.
`undefined reference to __asan_alloca_poison`.

I did some research and read about adding `-fsantitize=address` and `-shared-libasan` (or `-shared-libsan`) to `CFLAGS` AND `LDFLAGS`. I did that (for which I had to hard-code it into `build/build.sh`, isn't there a more convenient way?), but to no avail:

I ended up with
`aarch64-linux-android-ld: -f may not be used without -shared`.

So I tried reading up on ld's `-shared` flag and adding it to `LDFLAGS` (more like a guess really). Resulted in
`aarch64-linux-android-ld: -r and -shared may not be used together`.

Really don't know where to go from here and what's going wrong in general?

Any help really appreciated!

---

Update: At first it seemed that using `gcc` instead of `clang` seemed to resolve the issue. The phone boots up fine, buttons work, but the touchscreen does not respond. I am looking into the reasons...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the touchscreen you need to manually copy required drivers to the AOSP folder. You can obtain fresh drivers from the kernel source code.

```
     cd ${CONTAINER_GIT_REPO} && \
     cp arch/arm64/boot/Image.lz4-dtb \$AOSP/device/google/wahoo-kernel/Image.lz4-dtb && \
     cp arch/arm64/boot/dtbo.img $AOSP/device/google/wahoo-kernel/dtbo.img && \
     cp drivers/input/touchscreen/stm/*.ko $AOSP/device/google/wahoo-kernel && \
     cp drivers/power/*.ko $AOSP/device/google/wahoo-kernel && \
     cp drivers/input/touchscreen/synaptics_dsx_htc/*.ko $AOSP/device/google/wahoo-kernel && \
     cp drivers/input/touchscreen/lge/*.ko $AOSP/device/google/wahoo-kernel && \
     cp drivers/input/touchscreen/lge/lgsic/*.ko $AOSP/device/google/wahoo-kernel && \

# Building final image for Pixel 2

     cd \$AOSP && . build/envsetup.sh && lunch aosp_walleye-userdebug && make bootimage -j4 
    && mkdir -p ${CONTAINER_GIT_REPO}/builded_images && \
     cp out/target/product/walleye/*.img ${CONTAINER_GIT_REPO}/builded_images"
```

To obtain kernel source code:

`git clone -b android-msm-wahoo-4.4-oreo-m2 --single-branch https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm`

I have only Pixel 2 to check, but this should be applicable for both of them.

Update: You can check this repo for additional details https://gitlab.com/textor/build-pixel-2-in-docker

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the config file: ./private/msm-google/build.config.kasan
I used to use this config file and succeeded.

But the touchscreen didn't work, too.